# Spark union RDDs and preserve order

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I'm reading data from three separate CSVs into Spark RDDs (using pyspark).

```
sc = SparkContext()
rdd_list = []
feattable = ['csv1', 'csv2', 'csv3']
for idx, ftable in enumerate(feattable):
    print("Loading data from: %s" % ftable, idx)
    thisRdd = sc.textFile('hdfs:' + ftable).mapPartitions(lambda line: read_line_csv(line))
    thisRdd = thisRdd.map("some mapping no relevant to question")\
        .reduceByKey("some reducing no relevant to question")\
        .map("final mapping").persist()
    rdd_list.append(thisRdd)

rdd = sc.union(rdd_list).reduceByKey(lambda x,y : x+y)
print(rdd.take(5))
```

During the final mapping, for debugging, I get a tuple of `(user_id, list(len(csv entries per user))`.

I run the code once and get:

```
Loading data from: csv1 0
Loading data from: csv2 1
Loading data from: csv3 2
[('749003', [[2000], [9081], [100]])]
```

running again I get:

```
...
[('749003', [[9081], [100], [2000]])]
```

and again:

```
...
[('749003', [[9081], [2000], [100]])]
```

So you can see I'm getting a random order to the final list. I want the final list to reflect the order of `feattable`. How can I force the `union` to preserve the order the RDDs were appended to the list?

Comment: have you tried sortBy? [wiki](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/api/python/pyspark.rdd.RDD-class.html)

Comment: The problem is not the `union` but the `reduceByKey` which shuffles the data